# Symfony oauth2 and user disabled: why not access denied ?

Tags: symfony, oauth

I have a Symfony WebApp (REST) where user can authenticate via Oauth2 (fos oauth-server-bundle). I have a problem when the user is disabled: he/she can request a new access_token without problem so all functions of my app "crash". How can my server reply with an error ?

Comment: What do you mean by "user is disabled"? Which kind of grant-type do you use? How does your user provider look like? Please add some more information and some code snippets, the information given makes it difficult to help.

Comment: In the user bundle (FOS User bundle) there is the fields "status". oAuth2 (from FOS) use "user bundle" so I have thinked that if the user have status = 0 (disabled) then oAuth2 reply with an error. No ?

Comment: Well you should have a User Class, see http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html, Step 3. Please post the code of this class, then it's much easier to help.